# Spring boot validating @RequestParam not working in kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, validation, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to validate `text` parameter to be not blank in spring boot kotlin project, but its not working correctly and returning just response code 200 instead of 422.
`org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation"` is also present in classpath.

Controller.kt

```
@Validated
@RestController
@RequestMapping(ApiEndPoints.Search.SEARCH_ROOT_PATH)
class SearchController(
    private val searchService: SearchService
) {
    @GetMapping(ApiEndPoints.Search.BY_USERS)
    fun searchUsers(
        @Valid @NotBlank(message = "Text must not be blank") @RequestParam text: String,
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = Constants.DEFAULT_PAGE_0) page: Int,
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = Constants.DEFAULT_SIZE_15) size: Int
    ): ResponseEntity<ApiResponse.Success<Map<String, Any>>> {
        val users = searchService.searchUsers(text, page, size)
        return ResponseEntity.ok(ApiResponse.Success(true, users.createResponseMapFromSlice(Constants.USERS_LABEL)))
    }
}
```

ControllerAdvice.kt

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@RestControllerAdvice
class GlobalExceptionHandler : ResponseEntityExceptionHandler() {
override fun handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
        ex: MethodArgumentNotValidException,
        headers: HttpHeaders,
        status: HttpStatus,
        request: WebRequest
    ): ResponseEntity<Any> {
        val errors = hashMapOf<String, String>()
        ex.bindingResult.allErrors.forEach {
            val fieldName = (it as FieldError).field
            val errorMessage = it.defaultMessage
            errors[fieldName] = errorMessage.toString()
        }
        return ResponseEntity(
            ApiResponse.ValidationError(
                errors,
                ErrorCodes.VALIDATION_FAILED
            ), HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried without the `@Valid` annotation, so simply `@RequestParam @NotBlank(message = "Text must not be blank") text: String`?

Comment: You don't need the `@Validated` annotation in the class signature. Have you tried to move the `@RequestParam` annotation to the beginning? Also to know more about the problem could you create a test for it? We will be able to see the output easily

Comment: @joão-dias Tried it, but not working. also marking class and method as `open` didn't helped.